# Why CQL is suggesting me to use ALLOW FILTERING on update?

Tags: cql

My simple update query is throwing following error.

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=220 [Invalid query] 
message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and 
thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this 
query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

As far as I know ALLOW FILTERING adds indexing and it is usually used to SELECT query. I tried to understand the reason behind this error. But could not find anything. Also, I have just started to learn CQL few concepts are new to me.

Here is the schema of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE blogplatform.users (
    user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    active_status int,
    password text,
    user_name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Query I am trying to execute:

```
UPDATE users SET active_status = 0 WHERE user_name='Heath';
```

Output:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=220 [Invalid query] 
message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and 
thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this 
query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

I even tried to add ALLOW FILTERING in the query:

```
UPDATE users SET active_status = 0 WHERE user_name='Heath' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Output:

```
SyntaxException: line 1:59  : syntax error...
```

Could someone please explain me why I am getting this error on simple update. Also, can anyone guide me to resolve this error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a value column in the where clause (without allow filtering but again allow filtering is not a magic word and it just puts a lots of load on the database) - this is applicable for all type of queries and not just Select queries.

Better option for you would be to move the user_name as the PRIMARY KEY (PARTITION KEY).

With that table you can execute a query like.

```
UPDATE users SET active_status = 0 WHERE user_name='Heath';
```